# how to parse golang json array having random hash value in field name

Tags: arrays, json, go

I'm trying to parse JSON from API in golang code.
Of passed with `true` option argument it gives different additional info and with `false` different output.
I have covered that in the following golang play link:
https://play.golang.org/p/-JffO4AS01N

I need to parse the value of variable `mtJson`.

Used the Json to Go (https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) converted to get help in creating the struct type for this. But it was giving following struct type for the json example:

```
{
"result": {
"99c4d91acc2486955c98015fbbdf06239b983c9d93d5069c39d040702af88738": {
"size": 845,
"fee": 0.000144,
"time": 1547444481,
"height": 1183405,
"startingpriority": 89509.20245398773,
"currentpriority": 89509.20245398773,
"depends": []
},
"73f582cf419f8b1cd6a87f81e0e9a4e783add27c2be083361e8eb4a3bac0134e": {
"size": 1635,
"fee": 0.000312,
"time": 1547444435,
"height": 1183405,
"startingpriority": 341863.3540372671,
"currentpriority": 341863.3540372671,
"depends": []
}
},
"error": null,
"id": "curltest"
}
```

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Result struct {
        Nine9C4D91Acc2486955C98015Fbbdf06239B983C9D93D5069C39D040702Af88738 struct {
            Size             int           `json:"size"`
            Fee              float64       `json:"fee"`
            Time             int           `json:"time"`
            Height           int           `json:"height"`
            Startingpriority float64       `json:"startingpriority"`
            Currentpriority  float64       `json:"currentpriority"`
            Depends          []interface{} `json:"depends"`
        } `json:"99c4d91acc2486955c98015fbbdf06239b983c9d93d5069c39d040702af88738"`
        Seven3F582Cf419F8B1Cd6A87F81E0E9A4E783Add27C2Be083361E8Eb4A3Bac0134E struct {
            Size             int           `json:"size"`
            Fee              float64       `json:"fee"`
            Time             int           `json:"time"`
            Height           int           `json:"height"`
            Startingpriority float64       `json:"startingpriority"`
            Currentpriority  float64       `json:"currentpriority"`
            Depends          []interface{} `json:"depends"`
        } `json:"73f582cf419f8b1cd6a87f81e0e9a4e783add27c2be083361e8eb4a3bac0134e"`
    } `json:"result"`
    Error interface{} `json:"error"`
    ID    string      `json:"id"`
}
```

This doesn't seem right.

The value of the string hash key will be always different not determined, so can not just set that as is in struct.

I'm feeling confused on how to parse the JSON so that I can finally get the values like this:

```
fmt.Println(mt.Result.("99c4d91acc2486955c98015fbbdf06239b983c9d93d5069c39d040702af88738").Size)

fmt.Println(mt.Result.("99c4d91acc2486955c98015fbbdf06239b983c9d93d5069c39d040702af88738").Fee)
```

Please help

I have covered that in the following golang play link:
https://play.golang.org/p/-JffO4AS01N

I have covered that in the following golang play link:
https://play.golang.org/p/-JffO4AS01N

Expected:
fmt.Println(mt.Result.("99c4d91acc2486955c98015fbbdf06239b983c9d93d5069c39d040702af88738").Size)
845

fmt.Println(mt.Result.("99c4d91acc2486955c98015fbbdf06239b983c9d93d5069c39d040702af88738").Fee)
0.000144

Actual Result: {{0 0 0 0 0 0 []}}

Comment: Your title asks about unmarshaling arrays, but your question only mentions objects. Is the title just wrong, or is your question leaving out important details?

Comment: Thanks @ThunderCat will look and try the help from your provided link.

Comment: @Flimzy You can take a look at the value of `mfJson` and `mtJson`, `mfJson` is JSON array, so felt confusing with all that and since being new to golang, didn't sure how to put it in words here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the keys are not known, you have to resort to a dynamic data structure.

Define the single element like:

```
type Element struct {
            Size             int           `json:"size"`
            Fee              float64       `json:"fee"`
            Time             int           `json:"time"`
            Height           int           `json:"height"`
            Startingpriority float64       `json:"startingpriority"`
            Currentpriority  float64       `json:"currentpriority"`
            Depends          []interface{} `json:"depends"`
}
```

Then parse your json to a `map[string]Element` like so:

```
result := make(map[string]Element)
json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &result)
```

Comment: Thanks! yes your make map example helped understanding what I needed to do. Tried and it shows the result in output with this test: https://play.golang.org/p/dtt9CSIu1gR

Comment: So, do I have to use the for loop or `exists` to select the dynamic key and then output work with the data in that key's object? Or is there other better way?

Comment: Yes you should use for loop or exists

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciate your help. :)